# How to handle multiple check boxes created through map method

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple checkboxes which are created within `map(loop)`. I am unable to add two functionalities:

1. When the user clicks on any checkbox, it should show that checkbox checked
2. All event_id which are present in `eventGoing` variable should be checked by default.

```js
{
  products.map((post) => (
    <div>
      // eventGoing going contains the list of event ids which I extracted from DB
      if(eventGoing.indexOf(event_id) > -1)
      {
        // need to check the checkbox if event_id is within eventGoing variable
      }
      <input
        checked={checked}
        name="goingChk"
        value={"checkbox-" + post.event_id}
        type="checkbox"
        id={"checkbox-" + post.event_id}
        onClick={(e) => handleGoing(e, post.event_id)}
      />
      <br />
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Ignore the coding errors as I extracted the code from 2 different functional components.

Please help me out with how can I get the two functionalities mentioned above.

Comment: Just update `checked={checked}` to `checked={eventGoing.includes(post.event_id)}`

Comment: Adding this shows the checkbox checked which are present in eventGoing but when i click on checkbox, it doesn't check or uncheck it.

Comment: can you share your code in `handleGoing`?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

the problem is you are saving value on single boolean state, which is causing issue (checking all checkboxes)

**Solution**

Here is something you can try

```
 const products = []
  const [checkboxValues, setCheckboxValues] = React.useState(new Array(products.length).fill(false));

  const handleCheckboxChange = (index) => {
    const newValues = [...checkboxValues];
    newValues[index] = !newValues[index];
    setCheckboxValues(newValues);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {checkboxValues.map((value, index) => (
        <input
          key={index}
          type="checkbox"
          checked={value}
          onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(index)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
```

You can use replace products array with your products array in this code and that should work just fine.

Although if you want to do it inside your code you can do it like this

Sure here's updated example

Complete code:

```
const fetchDataEmpty = (setProducts) => {
    axios
        .get('/get_data.php')
        .then((res) => {
            const data = res.data?.map((item) => {
                return { ...item, checkboxValue: false }
            })
            setProducts(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Err:", err);
        });
};

const ParentTile = (props) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(setProducts)
    }, [type]) // []

    const handleCheckboxChange = (index) => {
        const newValues = [...checkboxValues];
        newValues[index].checkboxValue = !newValues[index].checkboxValue;
        setCheckboxValues(newValues);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {products?.map((item, index) => (
                <input
                    key={index}
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={item.checkboxValue}
                    onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(index)}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I understand i need to have array of state instead of having just one. However, i am bit new to React so unable to understand how to convert above code in my scenerio. Below is more explained code with parent and child component. Can you please explain how can i implement your code here:

Comment: Sure! please check my answer i have updated it as per your requirements